# How can I make my Samsung Series 9 laptop charge the battery to 100%?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, charging

I use a Samsung Series 9 laptop running Windows 7.

I notice that when I connect my laptop to its charger, it charges the battery up to 80% and stops there. I believe this is to extend long-term battery life, which is fine with me.

But, if I'm just about to leave my place with the laptop, I'd like to be able to tell my computer "please charge to 100% now, because I'm gonna need it."

Is there a way to tell my computer that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Quoting the official Samsung support site:

> Battery Life Extender sets the maximum battery charge level to 80% in order to extend the life of your battery.
>
> In order to turn Battery Life Extender off in Windows 7, you will need to access the BIOS. To access the BIOS and turn this function off, follow the steps below:
>
> 1. Turn your computer on.
> 2. When you see the Samsung logo appear, press the <kbd>F2</kbd> key repeatedly. The BIOS appears.
>
>    **Note**: If the BIOS does not appear, turn your computer off and follow the steps above again.
> 3. Use the right arrow key on your keyboard to move to the **Advanced** tab in the BIOS.
> 4. Use the down arrow key to highlight **Battery Life Cycle Extension**, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 5. Use the up/down arrow keys to select **Disabled** and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 6. Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to save and exit. Your computer will now start up and Battery Life Extender is disabled.
>
> <sub>Source: [Notebooks: Why Does My Battery Only Charge To 80%?](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00052165/73530/NP740U3E-K01UB)</sub>

Comment: Oh god... Disable this, then stab Samsung for this ridiculous invention.

Comment: @MaxRied Actually, [it's not ridiculous at all](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries).

Comment: Yes it is. There is little advantage but a lot of problems. Li-Batteries suffer less from being fully charged than from discharging entirely. If you remove 20% of its capacity artificially, it will be deep-discharged about 20% early, more often. Besides, this ruines the batterie stats. You won't notice when its capacity drops downto 80%, but when it reaches this point. You're battery won't live longer, you just get used to an broken battery before it actuall got down to 80%.

Comment: @MaxRied [Let us continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14356/discussion-between-and31415-and-max-ried).

Answer (score 0):

There is a piece of software that Samsung includes in their new computers that changes these settings for you. Open up the program labeled "Settings". It's icon looks like a volume knob with a purple background. Once in the program, go to the "Power Management" tab on the side. There will be a "Battery Life Extender" tab on the top. Turn the toggle switch to off and your battery should fully charge now. When you are done with your trip I recommend turning it back on as the Lithium Ion battery in modern electronics last the longest and work best when kept between 40-80% charge.